# having issue when converting a string into date frame to filter certain values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am reading a csv file and would like to filter rows based on a column that is in date format (i..e, yyyy/mm/dd). However, I am receiving an error `'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.date'`. It seems like the conversion that I apply does not go through.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime

#Suppose I read the following from an Excel file. 
x = pd.DataFrame([
    "4/11/2022",
    "6/16/2022",
    "12/18/2021",
    "11/13/2020",
    "5/17/2023"
                 ], columns = ["My Date"])

#I first convert the values into date format
x["My Date"] = pd.to_datetime(x["My Date"], errors = 'coerce').dt.date

#Then, I go ahead and try to extract values between two dates.
startdate = pd.to_datetime("2021-1-1").date()
enddate = pd.to_datetime("2022-1-1").date()
x["My Date"].loc[startdate:enddate]
```

My guess is that the conversion that I do with `x["My Date"] = pd.to_datetime(x["My Date"], errors = 'coerce').dt.date` is not working properly and was wondering if someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with regards to the conversion, the issue is `loc[]` accesses index values, which are integers. In your example your index is `[0,1,2,3,4]` which correctly is of type **int**, so when you pass **datetime** objects to `loc[]` essentially it is comparing int and datetime giving you the error. Consider using:

```
x.set_index('My Date').loc[startdate:enddate]
```

However, if you'd like to slice between two dates, then I suggest you use:

```
x_filtered = x[(x['My Date'] > startdate) & (x['My Date'] < enddate)]
```